# Set custom classpath maven-jar-plugin

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I want to add custom classpath to manifest file of my project. The classpath should point to all the files within a particular directory(lib). Something like 
`lib/.` or `lib/*`
Have tried specifying in entry to `manifestEntries` of `maven-jar-plugin` configuration but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly recommend how to do it ?

UPDATE

What I want is something like this-

```
<manifestEntries>
<Class-Path>lib*</Class-Path>
</manifestEntries>
```

I want to add all the jars present in the `lib` directory even though they may not be project's dependencies.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant section of your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following worked for me sometime back using classpathPrefix

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
          <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Original link: [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your lib folder is not inside the generate jar file?.I am not sure if that can help you. But you can include or exclude content in your jar file. Have a look [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)